# Image zoom using animate()

Tags: jquery

I have found one website for image zooming using animate(). But in that he had implemented on  elements. I am trying to make it to work on any image.

[Here is the link to the code](http://jsfiddle.net/tJDmJ/)

My requirement is to find an image tag automatically and apply this effect on it. For this i have changed the code

```
 $('ul.gallery li img')  to $('img')
```

assuming that below is my HTML code..

```
 <img src="/xxx.jpg"><p>jghjghjegejf</p><img src="/2.jpg">
```

But the zoom image is appearing at the left corner of the window.

[Here is the link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/y7Cee/)

Comment: Please post this to jsfiddle.net so we can interact in real time

Comment: @Bob Gregor thanks for your suggestion.. I have posted the code in jsfiddle as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is; the images are where they should be in their respective containers: http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/y7Cee/.

Comment: @Reddy: Can you make a JSFiddle with your entire code instead of just posting single lines? We can help you better that way.

Comment: @ JamWaffles Yes i have posted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the images in the original script is in an `<li>` with the following style applied:

```css
ul.gallery li { float: left; position: relative; width: 110px; height: 110px; }
```

The most important part is `position: relative`. This gives the images a point of reference to use to position themselves when growing. Since you're applying your code to images that aren't in `relative`-`position`ed elements, they're positioning themselves relative to the document as a whole.

You can't easily make the images behave this way without putting them in a container.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a minor edit that makes for a much smoother animation experience that doesn't queue multiple animations on mouseover: http://jsfiddle.net/Z97Qa/